# Adding ItemDecoration to Recycler View Causes Headers to Shrink

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that is using a StaggeredGridLayoutManager to display items that are sectioned by date. For each section(day) I have a header view that is inserted into the recycler view and in my OnBindViewHolderAction method I set the headers to be FullSpan. My issue is, when I add my ItemDecoration to the RecyclerView to give all the items spacing, the header views get covered by the spacing (as if padding were added without the view size increasing) instead of margin spacing being added. I am not sure where to look next, any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Without spacing item decoration:
[image]

With spacing item decoration:
[image]

What is should look like:
[image]

This last picture is the same RecyclerView and ItemDecoration but on a GridLayoutManager instead of a StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

```
public void OnBindViewHolderAction(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        var item = _collectionAdapter.SectionedList[position];
        if (holder is ActivityFeedItemViewHolder) {
            var viewHolder = (ActivityFeedItemViewHolder)holder;
            viewHolder.Bind((ActivityFeedItemViewModel)item);
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams)holder.ItemView.LayoutParameters;
            layoutParams.FullSpan = false;

        }
        if (holder is RecyclerHeaderViewHolder) {
            var viewHolder = (RecyclerHeaderViewHolder)holder;
            viewHolder.Initialize(((RecyclerViewHeaderItem)item).SectionName);
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams)holder.ItemView.LayoutParameters;
            layoutParams.FullSpan = true;
        }
    }



public override void GetItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)
    {
```

// STACKOVERFLOW NOTE: _headerTypeId is set to 0 when the method is called

```
        int pos = parent.GetChildAdapterPosition(view);

        // apply top spacing to first header only if there is one
        if (pos == 0 && _headerTypeId != -1) {
            outRect.Top = 2 * _spacing;
        }

        // these are fixed spacings for all cells
        outRect.Bottom = 2 * _spacing;
        outRect.Left = _spacing;
        outRect.Right = _spacing;

        // only apply spacing to the top row if we don't have headers
        if (_headerTypeId == -1) {

            // adjust the position index to account for headers
            for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
                if (parent.GetAdapter().GetItemViewType(i) == _headerTypeId) {
                    pos--;
                }
            }

            // apply top spacing to only the top row of cells
            if (pos < _layoutManager.SpanCount) {
                outRect.Top = 2 * _spacing;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: does the header layout have its height set to wrap_content?

Comment: This was the issue @Eugen Pechanec. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to fix this by simply setting the height of the header view to wrap content instead of having it set to a value in the axml (32dp in my case). Thanks to Eugen Pechanec.

Comment: Try adding `android:minHeight="32dp"` to produce desired result.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
outRect.Top = 2 * _spacing;
```

to

```
outRect.Top =_spacing;
```

if that is not working just comment that line and try.